# Passing .la or .a file as a library in cygwin in an attempt to run a python wrapper

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin

I'm trying to make an Iperf3 python wrapper work in cygwin. The wrapper requires Iperf3 to be installed and needs a library called "libiperf.so.0" to work. In Ubuntu, the wrapper automatically finds this  Iperf3 library. In cygwin, I compiled, built, and installed Iperf3 from source and it is working, so I'm assuming the library asked by the wrapper can be found.

However I could only find libiperf.a and libiperf.la on cygwin, not libiperf.so.0, and, from what I researched, those are the libraries used by Iperf when you compile, build and install it in cygwin.

So I tried passing libiperf.a and libiperf.la as libraries to the python wrapper. But I get either "OSError: Permission Dienied" (when passing libiperf.a) or "OSError: Exec format error" (when passing libiperf.la), followed by another "OSError: Couldn't find shared library <path_to_library>, is iperf3 installed?"

Here's the complete error output when i pass libiperf.la as library:

```
>>> client = iperf3.Client(lib_name="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libiperf.la")
Exception ignored in: <function IPerf3.__del__ at 0x6fffffd1b700>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 213, in __del__
    os.close(self._stdout_fd)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute '_stdout_fd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Exec format error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 418, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(role='c', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 108, in __init__
    raise OSError(
OSError: Couldn't find shared library /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libiperf.la, is iperf3 installed?
```

Here's the complete error output when i pass libiperf.a as library:

```
>>> client = iperf3.Client(lib_name="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libiperf.a")
Exception ignored in: <function IPerf3.__del__ at 0x6fffffd1b700>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 213, in __del__
    os.close(self._stdout_fd)
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute '_stdout_fd'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 418, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(role='c', *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/iperf3/iperf3.py", line 108, in __init__
    raise OSError(
OSError: Couldn't find shared library /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/local/lib/libiperf.a, is iperf3 installed?
```

According to this [question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87392/cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error) the Exec format error means the file format is not supported by the OS, but Iperf3 is working correctly on cygwin. So for some reason the libiperf.la or libiperf.a are working for Iperf3 but arent accepted by the wrapper.

Also could I trust the "OSError: Exec format error"? Because down in the error output it says the library couldn't be found. If the library couldn't even be found how can it say there was a format error?

I also tried

```
ln ./libiperf.a ./libiperf.so.0
```

and

```
ln ./libiperf.la ./libiperf.so.0
```

trying to trick the wrapper into accepting the libraries but I keep getting the same errors as before.

I feel like this wrapper cant be run in cygwin because of the different libraries iperf3 uses when its installed in the cygwin environment, but maybe not. Am I missing something to make this work?

Comment: libiperf.so.0 looks a Unix name not a Cygwin/Windows one. Are you trying to to build libiperf for Cygwin or what ?

Comment: iperf3 cygwin package has only the program not a shared lib, so probably you need to start building a shared lib before trying to involve python in the problem